# winbio.h header file functions are disabled?

Tags: c++, windows, windows-7, credential-providers

i am using VS 2010 in windows 7 express edition.

i also tried to get a `winbiocapturesample` function from this headerfile.but i have a problem to use winbio.h functions.this header placed in microsoft sdk v7.0a.

i will include that header file into my solution,after the below condition functions are  disabled.

```
#if (NTDDI_VERSION >= NTDDI_WIN7)
```

but i am using windows 7 only.can anyone tell what NTDDI_VERSION,why its not working.

if i try to debug `error C3861: 'WinBioOpenSession': identifier not found`

but,the 'WinBioOpenSession' is in that headerfile after check the above condition.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compiler can't predict what Windows version you're targeting. You have to set that. `NTDDI_VERSION` should be set to `NTDDI_WIN7` if you want to target Windows 7.

Comment: But,its a system headerfile,i try to change NTDDI_VERSION into NTDDI_WIN7 and try to save access denied error returned.

Comment: @ MSalters : i copy the headerfile and create new one for my own modification.now it works.thank u.

Comment: @SanjuMonu: That's entirely not how it works. You set it by `#define NTDDI_VERSION NTDDI_WIN7`.